# Excel, vlookup from 3 columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have this 2 sheets:

```
[Sheet1]
number|date  |name|state|rut
----------------------------
    1 |May-02|An  |true |34


[Sheet2]
number|rut|name|date  |more data
------------------------------
    1 |34 |An  |May-02|xxx
```

How can I cross those two sheets into another one?

I need to get this:

```
[Sheet3]
number|date  |name|state|rut|more data
------------------------------
    1 |May-02|An  |true |34 |xxx
```

So I need to find the data by 3 columns: number, date and rut

I know how to do it by one, with

```
=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A1;Sheet2!A:A;1;)
```

But I don't know how with 3 columns in different possition

Answer (score 0):

In Sheet2 insert a helper column between 'date' and 'more data' ( Column E). Now populate this column with A2&"|"&D2&"|"&C2&"|"&B2 ( I am assuming in Sheet2, columns  'number','rut','name','date' are A,B,C and D respectively ). Copy the folmula in rows below.So you have effectively composed a key combining number,date, name and rut in column F. Now in Sheet1, in column F, build the key A1&"|"&B1&"|"&C1&"|"&E1.Copy these formulas in all the rows. Now do the vlookup on column F in Sheet1, with matching column E in Sheet 2 and get the 'more data' values.
There is nothing particular about character "|", you may use any other unique character which you know is not appearing in your data.

Comment: Actually I did something like that. I create a column with a compose key by those 3 columns, then I find on that entire column what I need, thanks

Comment: "you may use any other unique character which you know is not appearing in your data." you may also use A) any other character or B) no character at all

Comment: Yes @Alex M, no character is required in this case. But having a visible separator is a good practice and it is very useful when you have consecutive parts which are both numeric or both charater strings.